# POSTGRES TRIGGER FUNCTION Fails to formart JSON PAYLOAD

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, insert

I have a table in postgresql that need to store a function and a trigger that will notify my server and send the column table and values as a json payload, however on the function the lines below execute and create the function

-- Get required fields

```
  CREATE FUNCTION api.alarm_siren() RETURNS trigger AS $trigger$
DECLARE
 rec RECORD;

 payload TEXT;
 column_name TEXT =  ARRAY['column_name'];
 column_value TEXT;
 payload_items JSONB;
BEGIN
 -- Set record row depending on operation
 CASE TG_OP
 WHEN 'INSERT', 'UPDATE' THEN
    rec := NEW;
 WHEN 'DELETE' THEN
    rec := OLD;
 ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unknown TG_OP: "%". Should not occur!', TG_OP;
 END CASE;
 
 -- Get required fields
 FOREACH  column_name IN ARRAY TG_ARGV LOOP
   EXECUTE format('SELECT $1.%I::TEXT', column_name)
   INTO column_value
   USING rec;
   payload_items := coalesce(payload_items,'{}')::jsonb || json_build_object(column_name,column_value)::jsonb;
 END LOOP;

 -- Build the payload
 payload := json_build_object(
   'timestamp',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   'operation',TG_OP,
   'schema',TG_TABLE_SCHEMA,
   'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
   'data',payload_items
 );

 -- Notify the channel
 PERFORM pg_notify('notify_alarm_siren', payload);
 
 RETURN rec;
END;
$trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger beep_alarm_siren after
insert
or
delete
or
update
on
api.mpesa_c2b_txn for each row execute procedure api.alarm_siren();
```

However, attempts to insert data in the DB are futile and result in the error seen below

````
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function api.alarm_siren() line 20 at FOREACH over array
SQL state: 22004```
````

Comment: Pretty sure that should be `TG_ARGV[]` per [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). It would also help to see how you defined the trigger on the table. Add as update to question.

Comment: I am not seeing any arguments passed to the function in the error message. Add as update to question. Also the rest of the function would be nice.

Comment: i HAVE edited my question with the whole function and trigger @Adrian Klaver

Comment: `TG_ARGV[]` is for arguments passed into the function in the trigger e.g. `api.alarm_siren(arg1, arg2)`. You are not passing in any arguments so there is nothing to loop over. You need to spend some time here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: ON I realised the very same thing after you pointed me to it... Thank you. May God bless you